# GridView height of row

Tags: android, gridview

How to make row height fit the tallest item in GridView?
Because by default it's fail.
[image]

update:
here is layout with grid

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gird"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dip"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is layout of grid item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_item_background"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

this is background drawable of grid item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#F2DBA7"
        android:startColor="#F2DBA7" />

    <corners android:radius="7dip" />

    <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#C90E0E"/>

    <padding
        android:bottom="5dip"
        android:left="5dip"
        android:right="5dip"
        android:top="5dip" />

</shape>
```

this is source code of activity

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.GridView;

    public class GridActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gird);

            ArrayAdapter<String> answeredWords = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.grid_item);
            grid.setAdapter(answeredWords);
            answeredWords.add("123456789101234567891012345678910");
            answeredWords.add("12345678910");
            answeredWords.add("12345678910123456789101234567891012345678910");
            answeredWords.add("12345678910");
            answeredWords.add("12345678910123456789101234567891012345678910");
            answeredWords.add("1234567891012345678910");
            answeredWords.add("1234567891012345678910");
            answeredWords.add("1234567891012345678910");
            answeredWords.add("1234567891012345678910");
            answeredWords.add("1234567891012345678910");
            answeredWords.add("123456789101234567891012345678910");
            answeredWords.add("123456789101234567891012345678910");
        }
}
```

UPDATE:
I rewrote the GridView, he find the maximum height of the element row and sets all the elements of this row the same height.

Comment: Hai..did you find the solutions.?? if yes pls post it...

Comment: hey, can u upload your latest code which you have update, i am facing same problem.

Answer (score 2):

set col height dynamically 
if yo are using imageview as gridview's cell try to set iamgeview scale type

Comment: or just set textviews height wrap_content

Comment: you're talking about height of the gridviev, I'm talking about the height of the row. I want set the row height with respect to the maximal element, because by default elements overlap each other.

Comment: what you have to do is set gridview's and textview height as wrap_content so that it will adjust automatically and your textview height means your girdview's row height

Comment: I did so, but as you can see if one of the elements above the other, they begin to overlap each other.

Comment: try padding and horizontal spacing and yeah give all gridviews rows same height i mean just identify your tallest item then set its height to all your textview

Comment: I have set paddaing, but as you can see it still does not help.

Comment: i will chk it n get back to you ASAP

Comment: i guess your col height and width was not in proportion just set textview's height and width statically say 90dp in xml or dynamically

Comment: No, thank you. I rewrote the GridView, he find the maximum height of the element row and sets all the elements of this row the same height. result can be seen here https://www.dropbox.com/s/4fbhh9mu8rbbxrr/Screenshot_2012-06-05-10-11-40.png

Comment: can you please post what you've changed in GridView to fit your needs ? You can post it as an answer to your own question (and I'll vote for it ^^)